# Angular 6 Change Route Without Redirecting Not Showing On ActiveRoute

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**Purpose:**
I am creating search functionality where I'd like to be able to search for something, have the URL change, but not have Angular navigate to the route with the query string. For example: if I search for the world 'hello', the URL should change to /search?q=hello. The caveat here is that I have a `canDeactivate` guard that when returning false, resets the URL to the entry page. Since in this case the method I am using to change the URL in the browser is not changing the route, this reverts back to /search.

**What I have so far:**
I've seen a few examples of how to change the browser URL without redirecting Angular by using `location.go` or `location.replaceState`.

While this works for changing the browser URL, I need to change the actual router state without redirecting the page. So for example: if I do something similar to:

`location.replaceState("search", "?parameter=testing")
console.log(this.route.snapshot);`

I do not get the replaced state as the URL or any of the parameter keys. I only receive the entry page (in my case /search).

**Question**:
How can I change Angular router without triggering navigating to a new page? OR, how can I get my `canDeactivate` guard to redirect to the correct URL instead of the entry state?

Comment: Can you just store the search param in your localstate instead of your url?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the use-case a bit. My apologies for being a bit scant on the details. I've tried to use router.navigate, however, that results in the page reloading since the params change which results in an infinite loop reloading. Maybe i can update the router manually without triggering a change?

Answer (score 0):

Not deleting this in-case it helps anyone else. router.navigate was working correctly with how I needed it, however my subscription to listen to route parameters was firing off events from router navigation changes. I updated my route parameters to only fire on page load to prevent an infinite loop and to prevent my page from breaking.